# MahApps DataGrid unable to take user input and write to csv

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid, mahapps.metro

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry, if my code is junior. I am new to C#.

**Problem**

I've dynamically create multiple `DataGrids` in a `flyout`, using *MahApps*.  The `DataGrids` are populated by **CSV** files (`ConvertCSVtoDataTable()`). I want the user to be able to make changes to the `DataGrids` and when they are done, The `DataGrids` values will replace the **CSV** files(`UpdateDataGridParameter()`).

UI Tree:  `Flyout` > `StackPanel` > `GroupBox` >  `DataGrid`

**Issue**

`DG.SelectAllCells()` does not select from the user changed `DataGrid`.  How can I get the VISUAL UI representation of the `DataGid` or bind the  DT property to a data change event.  I hope I explained this correctly.  If you have any questions that can help me please post and I will respond quickly. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace SpiderRoll.Classes
{
    public class DataGridProperties 
    {
        private int IDValue;
        public int ID
        {
            get { return IDValue; }
            set { IDValue = value; }
        }

        private string HeaderValue;
        public string Header
        {
            get { return HeaderValue; }
            set { HeaderValue = value; }
        }

        private string DescriptionValue;
        public string Description
        {
            get { return DescriptionValue; }
            set { DescriptionValue = value; }
        }

        private string NameValue;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return NameValue; }
            set { NameValue = value; }
        }

        private string FilePathValue;
        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return FilePathValue; }
            set { FilePathValue = value; }
        }

        private DataTable DTValue;
        public DataTable DT
        {
            get
            {
                return DTValue;
            }
            set
            {
                DTValue = value;
            }
        }

        public static DataGridProperties DataGridObject(List<DataGridProperties> TBP, int ID = 0, string Name = "")
        {
            foreach (var tb in TBP)
            {
                if (tb.ID == ID || tb.Name == Name)
                {
                    return tb;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public static int FindDataGridID(List<DataGridProperties> DGP, string Name = "")
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var dg in DGP)
            {
                if (dg.Name == Name)
                {
                    return i;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public static GroupBox DataGridPropertieStackPanel(DataGridProperties DataGrid)  // DataGridProperties DataGrid
        {
            GroupBox GB = new GroupBox();
            GB.Header = DataGrid.Header;

            StackPanel SPMain = new StackPanel();
            SPMain.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;

            System.Windows.Controls.Label LBDescription = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
            LBDescription.Content = DataGrid.Description;
            LBDescription.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
            SPMain.Children.Add(LBDescription);

            StackPanel SP = new StackPanel();
            SP.Name = DataGrid.Name;
            SP.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
            SP.Margin = new Thickness(10);

            System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid DG = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();
            DG.Name = DataGrid.Name;
            DG.CanUserAddRows = false;
            DG.ItemsSource = DataGrid.DT.DefaultView;


            SP.Children.Add(DG);
            SPMain.Children.Add(SP);
            GB.Content = SPMain;
            return GB;
        }

        public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string FilePath)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FilePath);
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            string[] firstLine = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
            DataRow fl = dt.NewRow();
            int idx = 0;

            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                //If bool is in first row, turn the column into a checkbox.
                if (firstLine[idx].ToLower() == "true" || firstLine[idx].ToLower() == "false")
                {
                    column = dt.Columns.Add(header, typeof(bool));
                }
                else
                {
                    column = dt.Columns.Add(header, typeof(string));
                    column.ReadOnly = true;
                }
                if (header.EndsWith("~"))
                {
                    column.ReadOnly = true;
                }
                //Reading and building the first row
                fl[idx] = firstLine[idx];
                idx++;
            }
            //Adding first row
            dt.Rows.Add(fl);

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] rows = line.Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;
        }

        public static void UpdateDataGridParameter(DataGrid DG)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            IEnumerable<string> columnNames = DG.Columns.Cast<DataGridColumn>().
                                              Select(column => column.Header.ToString());

            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

            DG.UnselectAllCells();
            DG.SelectAllCells();
            foreach (DataRowView row in DG.SelectedItems)
            {
                IEnumerable<string> fields = row.Row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
            }
            DG.UnselectAllCells();
            var filePath = @"C:\IO\" + DG.Name + ".csv";
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

In Class Bundle, I create a list of DataGrids

```
    private List<DataGridProperties> dataGridList;
    public List<DataGridProperties> DataGridList
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridList;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridList = value;
        }
    }
```

In `Main`, I iterate the `DataGridlist` and populate `StackPanels` by calling the `DataGridPropertieStackPanel` function.

```
                        foreach (var item in bundle.DataGridList)
                        {
                            if (item.Name == DataGrid.Name)
                            {
                                sPanelParameters.Children.Add(DataGridProperties.DataGridPropertieStackPanel(item));
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Use 'ObservableCollection' instead of 'List'. And also refer [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to use Two Way bindings.

Comment: Thanks, Akansha I will look into this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataGrid updates the binded DataView once you change the values. You don't have to select and unselect the grid rows, just access the dataview directly. Slightly changed version of your code:

```
public static void UpdateDataGridParameter(DataGrid dataGrid)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var dataView = dataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView;
    var columnNames = dataView.Table.Columns
            .Cast<DataColumn>()
            .Select(column => column.ColumnName);

    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

    foreach (DataRowView row in dataView)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fields = row.Row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
    }

    var filePath = @"C:\IO\" + dataGrid.Name + ".csv";
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Gosha - dataView dataset is still showing the unmodified datagrid values.  I'm assuming "DG.ItemsSource = DataGrid.DT.DefaultView;" is the problem.  Thanks for the input.